# How to replace dataframe values based on index statistics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
l2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
index = ['FORD','GM']
df = pd.DataFrame(l1,l2).reset_index().T
df.index = index
```

I want to replace these integer values based on this:

For every index, if the value is less than mean-2, then it is 'MINI' else 'MEGA'.

Here the mean varies for every row.

The desired out looks like this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FORD | MINI | MINI | MINI | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA |
| GM | MINI | MINI | MINI | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA | MEGA |

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare each row to its [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) - 2 and if it is ≤ ([`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html)) assign the MINI/MEGA values with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
out = df.copy()

out[:] = np.where(df.lt(df.mean(axis=1).sub(2), axis=0), 'MINI', 'MEGA')
```

Output:

```
         0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
FORD  MINI  MINI  MINI  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA
GM    MINI  MINI  MINI  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible option :

```
vals = {True: "MINI", False: "MEGA"}

out = df.lt(df.mean(axis=1).sub(2), axis=0).replace(vals)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
FORD  MINI  MINI  MINI  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA
GM    MINI  MINI  MINI  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA  MEGA

[2 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Can you please explain `df.lt(df.mean(axis=1).sub(2), axis=0)` especially  `df.lt(..., axis=0)`? @Timeless

Comment: `df.mean(axis=1).sub(2)` to compute the *mean-2* of each row : `'FORD'/13.5, 'GM'/3.5`. `df.lt(..., axis=0)` to compare each value of the DataFrame *row-wise* with the *means-2* above.

Comment: I hope I understood it. Because of that, it's resulting in a DataFrame of boolean values where True indicates that the condition is met (value < mean - 2)?

Comment: That's correct. And throughout the entire process, we can say that there are [3 steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNttl.gif).